# How can I install protoc on Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, protoc

I'm running a cloud based gpu on a Linux distribution.
I need to run the following:

```
protoc --python_out=. ./mint/protos/*.proto
```

I install protobuf with:

```
!python -m pip install protobuf
```

When I execute

!protoc --python_out=. ./mint/protos/*.proto
I get the error:

```
/bin/bash: protoc: command not found
```

I also attempt:

```
protoc --python_out=. ./mint/protos/*.proto
```

This also gives me an error.
How can I install and execute protoc on this system?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1072684. Addressing your line, "!python -m pip install protobuf". You'll have a better experience going forward using `%pip install` in notebooks. (Similarly for `conda`.) Current best practices for running installs with pip inside a notebook would suggest that command as `%pip install protobuf`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the active notebook.

Comment: Which aspect of that pointed you in the right direction?

Comment: Installing instructions for ubuntu, they're slightly different than the regular pip install and also the % in front of the pip is definetely helpful.  I usually use the pip regular or !pip @Wayne

Comment: Glad it sounds like it worked out. About the exclamation point use with `pip`, [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) provides insight into why that can lead to issues and gives a sense of why the magic command was added.

Comment: Quick question when I install I can see: Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages.  protoc --python_out=. ./mint/protos/*.proto.  When I run the above I see "SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator" am I running it incorrectly?  @Wayne

Comment: So the SyntaxError looks different than in your original post, and so I hope you are making progress. Did you try running `!protoc --version` or `!protoc` alone or `!protoc --help` or `!protoc --man` or `!protoc -h` to just get the usage information for `protoc` from in your notebook? If `!protoc --version` basically works from inside the notebook than you are just doing the rest of the command with a syntax error just as it says. And if so, maybe try quotes around the path. I'm not familiar with `protoc` so I'm not set up to actually test it.